# How to make a Unit Test of an Angular Component which has a TemplateRef as Input?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular2-template

I am trying to write unit tests for an Angular component which can hide/show some contents passed as input to the component itself.
The inputs expected are defined as TemplateRef.

**my-component.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: "my-component",
    templateUrl: "./my-component.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./my-component.component.scss"],
    exportAs: "mycomponent"
})
export class MyComponent {
    private _expanded = false;

    @Input()
    set expanded(value: boolean) {
        this._expanded = value;
    }

    @Input()
    body: TemplateRef<any>;
    @Input()
    handler: TemplateRef<any>;

    constructor() {}

    toggleView() {
        this.expanded = !this._expanded;
    }
}
```

**my-component.component.html**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <!-- Header -->
    <main #header>
        <header (click)="toggleAccordion()">
            <div class="handler">
                <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="handler">
                </ng-container>
            </div>
            <i class="icon icon-expand" [ngClass]="{ 'icon-expand': _expanded, 'icon-collapse': !_expanded }"></i>
        </header>
    </main>
    <!-- Body -->
    <div class="body" *ngIf="_expanded">
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="body"></ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to test if the content passed through the input "body" is visible or not, but I can't figure it out how to instantiate in jasmine a "my-component" with a TemplateRef input.

[The Angular documentation explains how to pass an input](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-inputs-and-outputs) on the unit test script, but since I can't instantiate any TemplateRef object because TemplateRef is an abstract class, I don't know how to manage this.

**my-component.component.spec.ts**

```js
...

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [MyComponent]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.body = /* What should I put here? */;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

....
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'll try to give you a demo code which you can extend further

Basically, you need to test this in a different way. Since you can't create your component without using `TemplateRef` of another component, so you need to create a wrapper component and **test your component by writing test case for WrapperComponent**

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ng-template #div1>Something here</ng-template>
    <ng-template #div2>Many things here</ng-template>
    <my-component [expanded]="expandedVal" [body]="div1" [handler]="div2"> </my-component>
  `,
})
class WrapperComponent {
     @ViewChild(MyComponent, { static: true }) appComponentRef: MyComponent;
     public expandedVal = true;
}

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let app: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WrapperComponent>;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [WrapperComponent, MyComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WrapperComponent);
    const wrapperComponent = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    app = wrapperComponent.appComponentRef; // this is where you get "MyComponent" component for testing
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    expect(app).toBeDefined();
  }));
});
```

Comment: The article that led me here that you wrote https://shashankvivek-7.medium.com/testing-angular-component-with-templateref-as-input-b96313b37cd4 was very helpful

Comment: @BenTaliadoros: This appreciation means a lot. Thanks Ben ! :)

Comment: I could not get the above example to work initially. I had to declare the ViewChild like this `@ViewChild(ChildComponent, { static: true })` to make it work. This means the child is resolved before change detection happens, which in the example happens _after_ the component is assigned to the test property.

Comment: @FantasticJamieBurns thank you. That was missing here.