# Get injector passed to component in testing (parent injector)

Tags: angular

I acquire an injector the following way:

```js
constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
) {}
```

I then create a new injector, and use this one as the parent (I'm opening a material dialog here, but I don't think it's relevant to the question):

```js
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CoolDialogComponent, {
    data: { /* cool data */ },
    injector: Injector.create({
        providers: [/* list of cool providers */],
        parent: this.injector,
    }),
});
```

Now, in the tests, I need to check if the dialog is opened with the correct parameters, and thus, need a reference to the exact injector:

```js
expect(dialogSpy.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(CoolDialogComponent, {
    data: {},
    injector: Injector.create({
        providers: [],
        parent: /* need the exact injector passed to the component */,
    }),
});
```

Is there a way to get this reference, or is a new injector constructed for each component (<s>– which would make this impossible, I guess?</s> I think I should still be able to somehow acquire component specific things, if that's the case)? I've tried to use the following values: `fixture.componentRef.injector`, `fixture.debugElement.injector`, `TestBed.inject(Injector)`, and probably a few others I don't remember. However, none of these seem to be the exact injector passed to the component.

Currently, I've resorted to making the injector of the component public (`constructor(public injector: Injector)`), and using `component.injector`. That works, but I don't want to do this, and shouldn't have to do this.

## TL;DR

How to get a reference to the exact `Injector` passed to the component whilst testing.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! So it looks like there is an injector for each individual component (which is probably obvious to more experienced angular users, but I wasn't aware).

The issue with my code was, that I'm using a wrapper component in my test ([because unrelated template stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57019955/10315665)):

```js
@Component({
    template: `<app-cool-dialog-opener>
        <ng-template let-entity>{{ entity.name }}</ng-template>
    </app-cool-dialog-opener>`,
})
class WrapperComponent {
    @ViewChild(CoolDialogComponent, { static: true })
    coolDialogOpenerComponent!: CoolDialogOpenerComponent;
}

// ...

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WrapperComponent);

component = fixture.componentInstance.coolDialogOpenerComponent;
```

So I'm assuming, `fixture.componentRef.injector` returned the injector that would have been passed into `WrapperComponent`.

**How I actually solved this, simple query the directive, and use that injector:**

```js
fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(CoolDialogOpenerComponent)).injector
```

That returns the injector I desired.

I hope this can save somebody an hour or two :)